# Slowness while calling tpinit and tpterm function in multithreaded programe

Tags: c, multithreading, tuxedo

`tpinit` and `tptern` tuxedo function taking time. Its basically used in every request by client to join and leave the application. we observed heavy slowness when number of request is higher from a multi-threaded client process.

We try to increase the virtual core in machine but still face the same problem.

```
TPINIT   *   tpinitbuf;
if((tpinitbuf = (TPINIT *)tpalloc("TPINIT",(char *)NULL,TPINITNEED(16))) == (TPINIT *)NULL)
{
    printf("ERROR IS:: %s\n", tpstrerror(tperrno));
    return NULL;
}
tpinitbuf->flags = TPMULTICONTEXTS;
tpinit(tpinitbuf); //this function is taking time. 
tpgetctxt(&ctxt, 0);
tpfree ((char *) tpinitbuf) ; 
retVal=tpcall("MY_SERVICE",(char *)buf1,0,(char **) &buf2,&size,0L);
tpterm(); // this function is taking time.
```

Ideally `tpinit`, `tpterm` should take around 50 milliseconds, but when number of request is high its takes around 1.3 sec.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you do that? Do tpinit() once for thread and do tpterm() only when the thread terminates. If you create new short-lived threads all the time then switch to using a thread pool.

Think of "joining Tuxedo application" as "connecting to a database" - and connecting/disconnecting does not seem such a great idea anymore.

There is a number of things tpinit() has to do: register itself in the shared memory (takes semaphores to prevent concurrent updates), create a reply queue and register it in the shared memory (so BBL can clean up after crashed processes), lookup service-to-queue mapping, loading plug-ins, etc. Tuxedo could be faster at all of that but if you do that too often it's your own fault, not Tuxedo's.